# Get Facebook news feed with iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am starting out with the Facebook SDK for iOS and in my app I am trying to get the users news feed and load it into a uitableview. This is proving tricky.

I can't find any documentation on it either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using the Facebook SDK, you can call Facebook Graph API using:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/home" andDelegate:self];
```

to get the current user's newsfeed.  You can then use the returned data to populate your tableview.  More info about TableView can be found at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewStyles/TableViewCharacteristics.html

Comment: Instead of me/home, you can use <user>/feed

Answer (score 0):

This is a comment on the suggestion to use @"me/home" (I couldn't comment because i have low reputation so far)

As i understood you can't use me/home anymore for iOS or Android because Facebook won't let you use read_stream permission which is necessary for me/home. I mean you won't be able to pass a Facebook app review if you use read_stream permission

Instead you can use:
1) me/feed but it gives only user profile's posts and no newsfeed 
2) or get liked pages with me/likes and get each page's feed with page-id/feed