# How can I display a Facebook user's news feed on an iOS application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, facebook, ios4

I'm sort of new to xCode and iOS development.

I'm making an application where a User can sign in to their Facebook account.
Then their news feed comes up (which is in "most recent" posts).
It's like the Trickle (Twitter) app.

Is their any code on github or any documentation that could help me?

Any code would be appreciated.

Please & Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get Facebook News Feed iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205123/get-facebook-news-feed-ios) Welcome to Stack Overflow. A quick search and a better title would have helped you find your answer faster.

Comment: but see im new to this what do i do with that line of code?

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/src/Facebook.m It's on line 465

Answer (score 0):

For what you're trying to do most likely you'll need to implement the [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#ios).