# Is this possible to retrieve Facebook Newsfeed in uitableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is this possible to retrieve Facebook user Friend new feed on UItableView in ios Application using OAuth or any other technique.?

Like we can retrieve Twitter news feed using the below code.

http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/09/16/dealing-with-the-twitter-oauth-apocalypse/

Is their any sample similar code available for facebook,or both for  facebook and twitter(combine).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205123/get-facebook-news-feed-ios

Answer (score 0):

Use fbgraph. see this [tutorial](http://www.capturetheconversation.com/technology/iphone-facebook-oauth-2-0-and-the-graph-api-a-tutorial-part-2)  and also use google for find facebook developer documentaion and there see about fbgraph.